# Python dictionary pointers and pointer to a reference?

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, reference

I have the following class that simply create a dictionary of objects for me. Then copy the created dictionary, `main_dict`,  to a new dictionary `second_dic`.

```
import numpy as np

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_dict = dict()
    def add(self, k, val):
        self.main_dict[k]=val

main_obj = MainClass()
for i in range(1,5):
    main_obj.add(k=i, val=np.random.randint(1,10))

print(main_obj.main_dict)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 7}

second_dic = main_obj.main_dict.copy()
print(second_dic)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 7}
```

It seems Python doesn't support pointers like C++. So when I change a value in my `second_dic`, the changes won't reflect in my `main_dict`. I am wondering what are my options in order to have this happens.

```
second_dic[1]=1000
print(second_dic)
{1: 1000, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 7}
print(main_obj.main_dict)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your above code, the changes you make to `second_dic` won't be reflected in `main_dict` because why would they? Those two are two completely different dictionary objects.

If you *want* aliasing (though it's really not recommended anyway because it leads to hard-to-detect bugs) you have to assign the reference (kinda like the C++ pointers):

```py
second_dic = main_obj.main_dict # Now second_dic is a pointer to main_dict, in a way

second_dic[1] = 1000

print(main_obj.main_dict)
{1: 1000, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The address of `second_dic` and `main_dict` are different. So the changes made to `second_dic` will not reflect to `main_dict`. I used the same above code and displayed the address of them and as expected they are different.

```
>>> id(second_dic) # To print the address
1911354287192
>>> id(main_obj.main_dict) # To print the address
1911354286952
```

If you require the `second_dic` to point to the `main_dict`. we can do it as below.

```
>>> main_obj.main_dict
{1: 6, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 3}
>>> second_dic = main_obj.main_dict # pointing to the same location
>>> second_dic
{1: 6, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 3}
>>> second_dic[1] = 111 #Changes the value
>>> second_dic
{1: 111, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 3}
>>> main_obj.main_dict  # Value gets reflected.
{1: 111, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 3}
```